# Can't install SymPy lib on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install SymPy lib on ubuntu with command "sudo pip3 install sympy".
It doesn't work, after ~15 sec pause it answer "killed" and close dialogue:

```
"Collecting sympy
  Using cached sympy-1.9-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 MB)

Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from sympy) (1.0.0)

Installing collected packages: sympy

Killed"
```

Then I tried to download lib installer with "git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy.git" command, then "sudo python3 setup.py install". It also doesn't work, return:

```
"...
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sympy/integrals/rubi/rubi_tests/tests/test_exponential.py to test_exponential.cpython-38.pyc

byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sympy/integrals/rubi/rubi_tests/tests/test_logarithms.py to test_logarithms.cpython-38.pyc

byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sympy/integrals/rubi/rubi_tests/tests/test_trinomials.py to test_trinomials.cpython-38.pyc

Killed"
```

What is problem here, in my commands or in python/ubuntu version?

Comment: `Killed` most probably means there is not enough memory.

Comment: Checked this already, System load:  0.0               Processes:             110
  Usage of /:   52.6% of 7.69GB   Users logged in:       1
  Memory usage: 41%

Comment: do you install it on local computer or on server? Do you run in consoler/terminal? What `close dialogue` do you mean?

Comment: Im trying to install it on server in terminal. I mean install process ends